# PHP code for checking email says .info domains are invalid

Tags: php, regex

I have the following PHP code that checks if an email is valid:

```
if (eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]*[0-9a-z]\.)+[a-z]{2}[mtgvu]?$", $email))
    return true;
```

Works great but I found out today that if I try validate a .info email, it says it's invalid. Any ideas what I need to add/modify to make it return .info emails as valid?

Thanks

Ben

Comment: The `filter_var(...)` regex as Wrikken mentioned looks ok to me, though I haven't fully analyzed it (and won't) -- your regex and the other answers' variations would all exclude my totally legitimate .com email address that has a "+" in it. An address is "localpart@domainpart", careful reading of [RFC 5322 section 3.4.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) shows almost anything except another "@" is legal to the left of the "@" sign. `!#$%{*/+-=}|?@[192.168.10.1]` is a legal email address, as is `"This \"message\" is for Fred"@group.department.gallery.company.museum`

Comment: Please be aware that the `ereg` family of functions has been [deprecated in PHP 5.3](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[a-z]{2}[mtgvu]?` at the end means that the top-level domain can only be two or three characters long. If you want a quick hack to make it accept `info`, you can change `[mtgvu]?` to `([mtgvu]|fo)?`:

```
if (eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]*[0-9a-z]\.)+[a-z]{2}([mtgvu]|fo)?$", $email))
    return true;
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make it so any TLD is valid? this way when new ones come out, it will work.

Comment: Just replace this part at the end: `[a-z]{2}([mtgvu]|fo)?` with `[a-z][a-z]+` - this will match any TLD that is 2 or more characters. Or if you want to restrict it to at most 4 characters, use `[a-z]{2,4}`.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) echo 'yeey, valid';
```

If interested in the actual regex it uses: it's in the public php source ( http://gcov.php.net/PHP_5_3/lcov_html/filter/logical_filters.c.gcov.php, line 525)

Comment: I want to allow PHP 4 support so I wont be able to use this. I've changed my code to preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]*[0-9a-z]\.)+[a-z]{2}([mtgvu]|fo)?$", $email, $matches);

Comment: In that case, why not expect the future to happen, use filter_var if available, and for consistency use the regex I pointed out to you?

Answer (score 0):

To just allow .info as well:

```
if (eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]*[0-9a-z]\.)+[a-z]{2}[mtgvu]?(fo)?$", $email))
```

(added optional 'fo' to end)

Comment: It's `[mtgvuo]?`, so the last character is optional, which means it would work for country codes.

Comment: true... it's the [a-z]{2}[mtgvu]? that limits it to three characters.  So country codes fit in the [a-z]...

Comment: Ah. no .museum? And ICANN was thinking about selling new arbitrary TLD's a while back, I don't know how far along they are with that.

Comment: I think casablanca's fo-fu is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using a more RFC-compliant email parser, like [this one from Dominic Sayers](http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail/), or [this one from Cal Henderson](http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/) of Flickr.